# How to add substring in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to add substring in SQL ?

```
DECLARE @ssn varchar(11)
SELECT @ssn = '123456789'
```

Actually, i have the value in my database as 123-45-6789

I want to do it one query to get the output as 12-456789

Expected output is **12-3456789**

Comment: Is it on purpose, that the "3" is missing in your line "I want to do it in one query..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with STUFF:

EDIT: Your follow-up question:

```
DECLARE @ssn varchar(100);
SELECT @ssn = '123-45-6789';

SELECT STUFF(REPLACE(@ssn,'-',''),3,0,'-');
```

The old question:

```
DECLARE @ssn varchar(11);
SELECT @ssn = '123456789';

SELECT STUFF(@ssn,3,0,'-');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a hyphen, you can use `stuff()`:

```
select @ssn = stuff(@ssn, 3, 0, '-')
```

EDIT:

Removing a hyphen is quite similar:

```
select @ssn = stuff(@ssn, 7, 1, '')
```

Comment: it works .. but i did some change in my actual post. could you please help me with that